# Cannot install Epson WF-2010 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kubuntu, printing, epson

I'm unable to get a WF-2010 printer working with Kubuntu 12.04 (using the KDE printer settings). I've downloaded the amd64 drivers from Epson and installed them with dpkg. However, nothing much happens after install: a directory is created in opt but no additional drivers are available. I can manually unzip the PPD file I need, and install it, but I'm unable to print a test page (stays in the stopped state).

How am I supposed to install these Epson drivers?

Answer (score 1):

The driver/setup do not work correctly if `/opt` is a symlink. By changing my layout of my disk and making `/opt` a normal folder the install and printer worked without problem.

Comment: could you please clarify your answer here? (and perhaps you should accept it if it solved your problem?)

Comment: Was your `/opt` a mounted NTFS partition?

Comment: No, it was not a NTFS mount. It was a link to another hard disk, ext4 I think.